# Disabled Background Data notification

Tags: notifications, background-data

I have disabled my background mobile data. I want the setting this way, but as a result of doing so there is an annoying warning that I have background data disabled on the system tray that prompts me to press and enable background data.

How do I remove the warning?

Running ICS on two device that show the warning.

Comment: Most of the apps don't respect that setting.

Comment: Even more annoying: Most of the apps which do not respect this setting come from Google... And the corresponding API reference for developers just states, the app "should" respect it -- not *must* respect it, as one would think...

Comment: Someone removed my edit: I added that this also occurs on Lollipop 5.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Touch the notification and it will go away. Of course, this will re-enable background data.

The thing here is, it's meant to be annoying. Many of your apps use background data in order to sync themselves or receive updates, notifications or whatever from the network, and without it, they can't do that.

If apps [do background data *correctly*](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html) then this can actually save you battery, as well as make the apps appear more responsive when you actually do open them up to see what they have to tell you. Unfortunately some apps don't, which is probably why you decided you wanted it disabled in the first place.

You have a few options. In order from easiest to hardest:

- You can live with the notification.
- You can remove the offending apps and replace them with less offensive apps.
- You can hack the Android source code to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 4.4 and below, this can be done via the Xposed Framework if your phone is rooted (**warning**: at the moment this will set your phone to use the Dalvik runtime if you're currently using ART):

1. Download the Xposed Installer apk file (click the link to the right of *Download*)
   http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer
2. Download the RemoveRestrictedNotification module
   http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.adam77root.removerestrictednotification
3. Open the *Xposed Installer* app → *Modules* → check *RemoveRestrictedNotification* → back → *Framework* → *Install/Update* → *OK* (this will reboot the phone)

Support for Android 5.0 and up is in the works:
[[OFFICIAL] Xposed for Lollipop](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)